# If I gave someone my personal info willingly, can you get the police involved?

Tags: identity-theft

I recently gave a guy I met over the internet my bank account information and my social security number, even though I know it is stupid. Then he wired money from my account to western union.

Can I get him arrested?

Comment: You can always get the police involved. The worst thing that could happen is that they ignore you. Well... actually, the worst thing that could happen is that they get the impression you might be involved in the crime. Talk to your lawyer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can (and should) get the police involved. The correct legal word for this type of interaction is "fraud", and the police will be very familiar with the scenario you're describing.

Whether the perpetrator will actually be arrested depends on a lot of things, so no guarantees there. But talking to your local police is where you start, no matter how it ends up in the end.

Unfortunately this question isn't on-topic for this site, so don't expect it to stay up for long.

Comment: even if I gave t to him willingly

Comment: @melissa talk to the *police*, not the *internet*.